# Thingsboard 3.1.1 How to display the number of devices for every related asset

Tags: assets, device, thingsboard

I have a number of three assets, each asset containing a different number of devices.
I am using an Entities widget to display all the assets.
Please tell me how to display in a custom column of that widget the number of related devices for every asset.
Please look at the attached picture for better understanding.

Thank You !

[Assets and Devices Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJcdH.png)